# Get custom MarkupExtension from code

Tags: wpf

Is there any way possible to get access to a custom MarkupExtension from code-behind? eg.

```
<TextBox Name="text" Text="{my:CustomExtension}" />
```

I want to be able to get access to the 'CustomExtension' instance.

I've created my own lightweight binding, but this is the only real gap in the solution. If I set the above from code, then I can keep the CustomExtension instance in an attached property, but in the above case the XAML parser wont do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Markup extensions are "resolved" when the property is needed, in that moment they will be replaced by the value they provide via `ProvideValue`. You probably won't be able to get an instance unless you add something to your `MarkupExtension` which passes it along.

Comment: Thanks for the response HB. What do you mean by they are replaced by the value they provide? Is it not the case that (in the example above) TextBox does not have a reference to CustomExtension, but CustomExtension may have cached a reference to TextBox (for ongoing updates) after the ProvideValue() call? Therefore TextBox holds the value provided by ProvideValue() quite independently from any reference to CustomExtension (which I believe it *never* has).

Any ideas for "something" that can be added to MarkupExtension to pass itself along? :)

Comment: @Fil: Does your extension inherit from `Binding`? In that case it would be a bit different and a binding expression will be set on the bound object. In that case you can retrieve that expression using [`GetBindingExpression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.getbindingexpression.aspx) on the Text property. The expression's `ParentBinding` may contain your (boxed) `CustomExtension`.